# Can not install mariadb on amazon linux ARM: packages not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mariadb

Working fine on Amazon Linux with Intel arch but not on ARM. I have followed one of the many guides like this one: https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-mariadb-server-on-amazon-linux/

So executed:

```
sudo  amazon-linux-extras | grep mariadb
```

got version 10.5, so continued:

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo reboot
curl -LsS -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
sudo bash mariadb_repo_setup --os-type=rhel  --os-version=7 --mariadb-server-version=10.5
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo yum makecache
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

So far so good, now:

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client -y
....
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: MariaDB-common conflicts with MariaDB-server-10.5.17-1.el7.centos.aarch64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

"--skip-broken" argument does not help.

When trying version 10.10:

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client -y
....
https://dlm.mariadb.com/repo/mariadb-server/10.10/yum/rhel/7/aarch64/rpms/galera-4-26.4.12-1.el7a.aarch64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=mariadb-main clean metadata
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  MariaDB-server-10.10.1-1.el7.centos.aarch64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  galera-4-26.4.12-1.el7a.aarch64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  MariaDB-client-10.10.1-1.el7.centos.aarch64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

"yum --enablerepo=mariadb-main clean metadata" does not help.

I've tried all version between 10.5 and 10.10, all failing.
EC2 machine deployed right now (t4g.medium). Did not have any problems on intel arch last week with exactly same code.
What is wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: hi perhaps remove all the mariadb packages and try a fresh install with the latest version?

Comment: tried, the same problem. Overall i have dropped the idea to run ARM processor in EC2. Too many other problems/packages are broken, non existing (just had similar problems when installing superset).  T4g is just 10-15% cheaper then T3 instance but putting huge risk (unable to expand / install additional software). Sorry to say that - but clearly ARM is not yet ready for a wider use. Moved back to intel arch and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centos7 for non-x86_64 platforms is deprecated. Ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/deprecation-policy/

The RHEL7 that feeds Centos 7 ended supported for non-86_64 platforms. While Centos7 still [claims to be supported for aarch64](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product), they simply don't get bugs fixes (including bugs affecting the MariaDB development that got noticed and reported to RHEL, that got fixed in RHEL8 only) so for all intensive purposed its not maintained.

As such MariaDB is no longer performing releases for Centos/RHEL 7 on non-x86_64 platforms.

ref: [MDEV-30636](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30636)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the following error as me after running sudo yum install -y mariadb-server:

Last metadata expiration check: 2:52:09 ago on Mon Sep 25 11:08:33 2023.
No match for argument: MariaDB-server
Error: Unable to find a match: MariaDB-server

Work-around:

- yum list mariadb* -> This will list all the packages of MariaDB.
- sudo yum install mariadb105-server.x86_64 -> this will successfully
  install Maria DB.

Once installed successfully try these commands

- systemctl enable mariadb
- systemctl start mariadb
- systemctl status mariadb.service

Thankyou.